# How to stop a function when <esc> is pressed? OR how to catch a <esc> signal in vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, functions, escape

I have a function which calls another function that reads user input from `input()`.

```
function! fun1()
  call fun2()
endfunction

function! fun2()
  let temp = input("Please input:")
endfunction
```

What I want is when typing in the command area of vim with `Please input: xxx`, if I press `<esc>`, `fun1` will be stopped/ not executed.

How is it possible to do this?

Trying to catch the `<esc>` key with:

```
try
  let temp = input("Input: ") " show what is already there
catch "normal! <esc>"
  echo "esc catched"
finally
  echo "\n".temp
endtry
```

does not seems to work.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply use `<C-c>`? (At least I believe that is what it was made for)

Comment: Well, but `<esc>` is also a normal behaviour when you enter sth and don't want to do it anymore.  In general the key shouldn't matter, my question is how to catch it.

Comment: Depending on your usecase,  `inputdialog()` might be an option.

Comment: @Ralf that func is listed in the `deprecated` list in neovim, and suggested to use `input`. I think we should focus on the problem.